# Questions regarding Adjusted Gross Incomes and their calculation

Tags: india, interest, fafsa, adjusted-gross-income

I was recently asked to provide my AGI by a governmental service outside my country and was wondering about its calculation, since Indian Tax Returns (ITRs) don't have a specific header for it.

Should I take the 'Total Income' that I see on my ITR and add the interest I gained in that year to it?

When trying to look at the total deductions I had during the applicable financial year on my Form-16, I noticed a header called 'Gross Total Income', but, weirdly enough, the amount it stated was just barely above my salary, and didn't seem to include the income I'd gained through interest. What does this field actually indicate?

Alternatively, should I add the interest I see on my AIS portal to my Total Income and subtract deductions under Chapter VI-A from the resulting sum?